# SAPUI5 Combobox JSONModel

Tags: json, combobox, sapui5

I try to bind the data to a combobox, but don't get it solved.
I can see the model (modelData) and the data is in the model.

Could somebody tell me, if the structure inside of the result (EX_LABOR) correct is?

```
            <ComboBox 
            items="{modelData}"
            selectedItem="selectedItem"  
            selectedKey="keySelectedKey" 
            selectedItemId="idselectedItemId" 
            id="idComboboxLabor"
            placeholder="Datum" 
            textAlign="Initial" 
            textDirection="Inherit" 
            maxWidth="100%" 
            change="onChangeLaborDatum" 
            selectionChange="onSelectionChangeLaborDatum">
                <items>
                    <core:Item  key="{modelData>PatientID}" text="{modelData>/PatientID}"/>
                </items>
            </ComboBox>
```

I put the ajax request in the init function.

Controller:
        jQuery.ajax({
                url: aUrl,
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

```
                // create JSON model instance
                var oModelCombobox = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

                /* // set the data for the model
                    Result:
                    {"EX_LABOR":{"0":{"PatientID":3161,"Datum":"2014-12-08T23:00:00.000Z"},"1":{    */
                oModelCombobox.setData(data);

                // set the model to the core
                sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModelCombobox, "modelData");
                var aData = oModelCombobox.getProperty("/EX_LABOR");

                var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            //      oModel1.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
                    oModel1.setData({
                        modelData: aData
                    });
                    console.error(oModel1);
                    console.error(aData);
            //  });

            }
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRb11.png)

Would be really helpful, if one of you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correct the binding of the ComboBox items aggregation:

```
items="{modelData>/EX_LABOR}
```

Also EX_LABOR should be an array.

Plus you need to correct the binding of the Item text property (as mentioned by @Qualiture):

```
text="{modelData>PatientID}"
```

In general you should rethink your naming: "modelData" is a bad name as it is not clear that your model contains data, but it is not clear what kind of data. Furthermore it is recommended to use:

```
this.getView().setModel(model, name)
```

instead of storing it in the core.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. <items>
      <core:Item  key="{PatientID}" text="{/PatientID}"/>
     </items>

Comment: Tried this, but doesn't work:    items="{modelData>/modelData}"
    selectedItem="selectedItem"  
    selectedKey="keySelectedKey" 
    selectedItemId="idselectedItemId" 
    id="idComboboxLabor"
    placeholder="Datum" 
    textAlign="Initial" 
    textDirection="Inherit" 
    maxWidth="100%" 
    change="onChangeLaborDatum" 
    selectionChange="onSelectionChangeLaborDatum">
     <items>
      <core:Item  key="{modelData>PatientID}" text="{modelData>/PatientID}"/>
     </items>
    </ComboBox>

Comment: It should be EX_LABOR, which should also be an array.

Comment: this.getView().setModel(model, name) --> Uncaught TypeError: this.getView is not a function

Comment: What @matbtt says, **and** you have an incorrect preceding slash in your core:Item text field; it should be `<core:Item key="{modelData>PatientID}" text="{modelData>PatientID}"/>` (remember, it should be relative to the bound `items` property)

Comment: Sorry I'm new in this business. I get the result from a hana stored procedure and use xsjs. Where do I convert the resultset that I get an array?

Comment: [{"0":{"PatientID":3161,"Datum":"2014-12-08T23:00:00.000Z"},"1":{"PatientID":3161,"Datum":"2014-12-01T23:00:00.000Z"},"2":{"PatientID":3161,"Datum":"2014-10-28T23:00:00.000Z"}}]

Comment: items="{modelLabordatum>/}"

Comment: Please provide an example (e.g. via JS Bin).

Comment: okay, I got it. Thanks for your help. The problem was that I used sap.ui.getCore().setModel(... instead of this.getView().setModel(model, name). I did it, because I got an uncaught typeerror. But now I use this.getView(.. before I do the ajax request. Now I don't get a typeerror and it works.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I got it. The problem was that I used sap.ui.getCore().setModel(... instead of this.getView().setModel(model, name). 
I used it only, because I got an uncaught typeerror. But now I use this.getView(.. before I do the ajax request and I don't get a typeerror anymore and it works fine.

And really, thanks for your helpful and fast response!!! You gave me the right hints!

Comment: If it helped it is really appreciated to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @matbtt I would, but don't know where